# Processes customer invoices before than it does inventory issues (shipments)

Tags: acumatica

Customer first creates invoice for customer, then they should prepare shipment process.  Do you know a way to achieve this?

Today, in Acumatica you have to create SO, then shipment then Invoice.

Comment: Is this question about programming?

Comment: Depends on the 'way' of achieving what OP wants. If that way requires Customization of Acumatica platform than yes, otherwise no it's a question about usage of ERP product.

Answer (score 0):

First create a Sales Order.

Then go to Distribution->Sales Orders->Work Area->Enter->Invoices screen.
Use the ADD ORDER button to add the sales order to the invoice:
[image]

Auto-Release setting in Distribution->Sales Orders->Configuration->Setup->Sales Order Preference screen:
[image]

Comment: I thought in that option, but that updates inventory as soon as we released invoice, doesn't it? I need to have inventory as reserved until we know when to ship it.

Comment: Well does it or doesn't it? What leads you to believe that it does? That's a different problem than original question so I'd need to get some details about it. Where do you see inventory updated that you would like to skip, which screen/which field? I have updated my question to show how to disable Auto-Release but in latest version of Acumatica I'm not sure this setting applies.